# How does the logic of a reply section work with PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, message, forum

I am trying to make a *reply section* to a message forum in my website. Below is my code that will be referenced in pieces to let readers fully understand where I'm at and what my question is (**I realize this post is lengthy for the viewer, but I did my best to be accurate and detailed as possible**).`

```
<?
   $sqlMessage = "SELECT * FROM messages GROUP BY message_number";
    $resultMessage = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlMessage);
     if(mysqli_num_rows($resultMessage) > 0) {
      while($rowMessagesDetails=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultMessage)) {
        $messageUsername = $rowMessagesDetails['username'];
        $messageMessage = $rowMessagesDetails['message'];
        $message_number = $rowMessagesDetails['message_number']; // using this number for the next part to find the replies
        $messageDate = $rowMessagesDetails['date'];

        //Getting ALL replies that match the message_number in the MESSAGES table
        $sqlReply = "SELECT * FROM replies WHERE message_number='$message_number' ORDER BY date DESC";
        $resultReply = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlReply);
            if(mysqli_num_rows($resultReply) > 0) {
            while($rowReplyDetails=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultReply)) {
                $replyUsername = $rowReplyDetails['username'];
                $replyMessage = $rowReplyDetails['message'];
                $replyDate = $rowReplyDetails['date'];

                echo '<div class="user-details-box">
                            <div class="user-username">'.$messageUsername.'</div> 
                            <div class="user-date">'.$messageDate.'</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="user-message">'.$messageMessage.'</div> 
                        <div class="reply-section"> 
                            <div class="replies">
                                <p class="reply-link-button left-replies">Reply&nbsp;</p>
                                <p class="bullet left-replies">&bull;</p>
                                <p class="show-replies-link left-replies">&nbsp;Show All Replies</p>
                            </div> 
                            <div class="reply-details-box"> 
                                <div class="user-replies-box">
                                    <div class="reply-username">'.$replyUsername.'</div> 
                                    <div class="reply-date">'.$replyDate.'</div> 
                                </div>
                                <div class="reply-message">'.$replyMessage.'</div>
                            </div>
                            <form class="open-textbox" id="reply-form" action="reply.php" method="post">
                                <input type="hidden" class="message_number" name="message_number" value="'.$message_number.'">
                                <div class="right-reply">
                                    <textarea id="getReply" class="insert-reply" name="reply" placeholder="Reply."></textarea>
                                    <div class="right-reply-btn">
                                        <button id="reply-link" class="reply-link" type="submit" name="submit">Reply</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>';
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
?>`
```

The problem is, I'm trying to figure out what I need to do to query replies specifically in reference to the user that posted the comment; and have the replies stack underneath. I have made a **REPLIES** and **MESSAGES** table that each have a **message_number** that does this (Explaining with *example* input):

```
MESSAGES TABLE 
message_number: 1 //useful primary that we'll use in the REPLIES table
username: BuzzLightyear2018
message: Star Command do you read me?
date: 3/9/2018

REPLIES TABLE
reply_id: 1 //random primary to keep rows unique
message_number: 1 //foreign key from MESSAGES that connect the message with the reply 
username: CowboyWoody2018
reply: No, but I've got a stick in my boot!
date: 3/9/2018
```

*How* do I match the **message_number** from the **REPLIES** table to the **message_number** in the **MESSAGES** table and show ***all*** replies ***underneath*** the message here:

```
<div class="reply-details-box"> 
  <div class="user-replies-box">
    <div class="reply-username">**username from REPLIES here**</div> 
      <div class="reply-date">**date from REPLIES here**</div> 
  </div>
  <div class="reply-message">**message from REPLIES here**</div>
</div>
```

*Just to reiterate*:
I want all *replies* to stack underneath the message from **MESSAGES**; all I keep getting when trying to querying **$sqlMessage = "SELECT * FROM messages GROUP BY message_number"** and **$sqlReply = "SELECT * FROM replies WHERE message_number='$message_number' ORDER BY date DESC"** is shown in the image below:

[This shows the *same* message **twice** because it's querying each reply to each message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEkev.png)
Any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM messages GROUP BY message_number` ?? If `message_number` is the primary key, it will be unique, so this is kind of needless to GROUP BY. ... but anyhow, the reason you get a dupe of the main message, is that main message html is inside the while loop on replies. Need to shift it out above.

Comment: @IncredibleHat I agree. It doesn't change anything by grouping it. I think I left that in there when I was experimenting the other day with grouping. Anyways, if I were to take the main message out and put it above the loop, then how does it generate all of the messages in the loop? I have to have it in the loop in order to spit out each individual div with MESSAGE details right?

Comment: @IncredibleHat Oh, I understand now! Thank you for the swift reply!

Comment: I was writing up an example, but mtr.web got it up first. You move it outside the nested `while`, but still inside the first `while`.

Comment: Yes. You're very first line of code is nonsensical. This doesn't bode well.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I was trying to get this by myself for a week.

Answer (score 0):

@IncredibleHat is correct on both points.  You should be able to drop the `GROUP BY` and get the same results.  Also, the PHP portion of the code would look like this:

```
<?
   $sqlMessage = "SELECT * FROM messages GROUP BY message_number";
    $resultMessage = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlMessage);
     if(mysqli_num_rows($resultMessage) > 0) {
      while($rowMessagesDetails=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultMessage)) {
        $messageUsername = $rowMessagesDetails['username'];
        $messageMessage = $rowMessagesDetails['message'];
        $message_number = $rowMessagesDetails['message_number']; // using this number for the next part to find the replies
        $messageDate = $rowMessagesDetails['date'];

        echo '<div class="user-details-box">
                            <div class="user-username">'.$messageUsername.'</div> 
                            <div class="user-date">'.$messageDate.'</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="user-message">'.$messageMessage.'</div>'
                    '<div class="reply-section"> 
                            <div class="replies">
                                <p class="reply-link-button left-replies">Reply&nbsp;</p>
                                <p class="bullet left-replies">&bull;</p>
                                <p class="show-replies-link left-replies">&nbsp;Show All Replies</p>
                            </div>';


        //Getting ALL replies that match the message_number in the MESSAGES table
        $sqlReply = "SELECT * FROM replies WHERE message_number='$message_number' ORDER BY date DESC";
        $resultReply = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlReply);
            if(mysqli_num_rows($resultReply) > 0) {
            while($rowReplyDetails=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultReply)) {
                $replyUsername = $rowReplyDetails['username'];
                $replyMessage = $rowReplyDetails['message'];
                $replyDate = $rowReplyDetails['date'];

                echo      '<div class="reply-details-box"> 
                                <div class="user-replies-box">
                                    <div class="reply-username">'.$replyUsername.'</div> 
                                    <div class="reply-date">'.$replyDate.'</div> 
                                </div>
                                <div class="reply-message">'.$replyMessage.'</div>
                            </div>';
                    }
                }

                          echo '<form class="open-textbox" id="reply-form" action="reply.php" method="post">
                                <input type="hidden" class="message_number" name="message_number" value="'.$message_number.'">
                                <div class="right-reply">
                                    <textarea id="getReply" class="insert-reply" name="reply" placeholder="Reply."></textarea>
                                    <div class="right-reply-btn">
                                        <button id="reply-link" class="reply-link" type="submit" name="submit">Reply</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>';
            }
        }
?>
```

Comment: I have less than 15 reputation or I would up-vote your reply through my ceiling. Thank you guys!

Comment: I don't know if you can answer this related question (I don't know all the rules of related topics - additional questions, versus creating new ones), but how does the DOM now work that we have split the code up between queries? My 'show replies' and 'reply' buttons on all messages now only trigger to open up the last query. The DOM paths don't work anymore. $('.reply-link-button').click(function() {
     $('form').toggle('slow');
            $(this).parent().next().next('form').toggle('slow');
         });

Comment: I just added one function because the post was getting long.